# Selenium Tag Ruby Cucumber

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium-Webdriver with the ChromeDriver installed as well as PhantomJS to automate my test pack.  There are some scenarios that I would prefer to run in browser when my pack is running headless.  I can tag my scenario as `@selenium` but when it loads, it opens up in firefox.  How do I get it to open up ChromeDriver when using the @selenium tag please?

I have the following in my env.rb file to run in browser:

```
if ENV['chrome']
 Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
 Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
   :browser => :chrome,
   desired_capabilities: {
   "chromeOptions" => {
   "args" => %w{ window-size=1080,720 }
  }
}
```

)

I set chrome=true to run in browser via cmd.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. Do you open the browser with hooks? If so, you should show how you are indicating which browser should open. Alister Scott had some instructions at http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/27/running-headless-watir-webdriver-tests-using-a-real-browser/

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: The cucumber documentation in github (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) shows hooks as Before(@chrome) do... I always put my hooks in the hooks.rb, not in the env.rb file..

Comment: I've got it to open in Chrome using that, thank you @DaveMcNulla. What I'm finding now is it's setting selenium as the default driver for all tests instead of just the tagged scenarios.

Comment: it's probably better if you post that as a separate question so you can put the code in to show people.

Comment: No need, i found the solution that works.  i'll post it up should anyone else be curious.  Very grateful for your help

Comment: Where is tag is your code?

Comment: I've tagged my scenarios as @chrome, in my code I would place Before ('@chrome') do |scenario|.  I used ('@tag') to generalise the example

Answer (score 0):

The solution, following on from Dave McNulla's guidance is as follows:

```
Before ('@tag') do |scenario|
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
  :browser => :chrome,
  desired_capabilities: {
  "chromeOptions" => {
    "args" => %w{ window-size=1080,720 }
     }
   }
 )
  end
end
```

I've set it to open in Chrome, only because it's default download action doesn't open up a pop up window, it goes directly to the downloads folder which is ideal for my tests.